# OctoberCMS Get plugin's Dropdown values at frontend

Tags: octobercms

I have created one plugin (call it **Product**) using [Builder Plugin](http://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-builder) and inside it, i have a dropdown (call it **product_category** (Product Category))

Using **Builder Plugin**, i have added few **Key => Value** (Dropdown Category options) like below.

**Added Dropdown Options**:

[image]

**Showing Dropdown Options**:

[image]

Now i have one **CMS page** (call it **products**) which i am showing in front end, and in which i am showing the list of the products, which works fine using the code like below.

[image]

Now here comes my question/query, i have a **Product Category Dropdown** in front end as well in a same page and i want to get all the Product Categories which i have added using my Builder Plugin.

How can i get those ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys, eventually i have found out a solution thanks to [alxy](http://octobercms.com/forum/user/alxy)'s help though and here what i have come up with.

```
$parser = new October\Rain\Parse\Yaml;
$fields = $parser->ParseFile('/path/to/fields.yaml');

var_dump($fields);
```

Go [here](http://octobercms.com/forum/post/octobercms-get-plugins-dropdown-values-at-frontend) for more.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use model method to generate the options:

```
public function getProductCategoryOptions() {
    return ['pet' => 'Pet',
            'beauty' => 'Beauty'];
}
```

and after this use a mutator:

```
public function getProductCategoryAttribute($value)
{
    return $this->getProductCategoryOptions()[$value] ?? 'N/A';  // PHP7
}
```

Comment: This way it works. However, I had a scenario to get data from yaml file hence I came up with a solution by loading yaml file data. Appreciated. Thank you.